# Amazon Linux 2023 systemd dependencies on cloud-init: Getting ordering cycle

Tags: systemd, amazon-linux, cloud-init

I have a **templated** systemd service that depends on cloud-init to be done on Amazon Linux 2023.

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

After=cloud-init.target

[Service]
Type=exec
EnvironmentFile=/local/service/my.env
ExecStart=/local/service/myservice
Restart=always
User=myuser

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

A service instance has been enabled via `sudo systemctl enable myservice@1.service`.

Getting this:

```
multi-user.target: Found ordering cycle on myservice@1.service/start
multi-user.target: Found dependency on cloud-init.target/start
multi-user.target: Found dependency on multi-user.target/start
multi-user.target: Job myservice.service@1/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with multi-user.target/start
```

This worked on a very recent version of Amazon Linux 2023 and seems to not work now.  I'm walking through everything to track it down, but if anyone has insight, that would be awesome.

**UPDATE:** I changed the `WantedBy=` to `cloud-init.target`.  This seems to have fixed the problem.  I don't have time currently to track down the differences in dependencies between the previous AL2023 AMI and the current, but this should be good for the time being.